# It it okay to use Chakra UI hooks (useBoolean, useConst) for convenience in a project, or should I stick with built-in React hooks?

Tags: react-hooks, chakra-ui

I'm interested in these hooks: `useBoolean`, `useConst`. Technically, you can achieve the same behavior with the built-in hooks. But those offered by Chakra UI are more convenient.
What do you think? Is it okay to use the hooks in your project for convenience, or is it going to complicate things in the future and make it more difficult to maintain the project? Should I React built-in ones whenever possible?

Chakra UI is a big part of the project I'm working on.

Comment: It is completely alright to use Chakra hooks.